# Robbins–Monro algorithm

Tags: density-function, stochastic-approximation

I don't have much knowledge about advanced math. I read an article about Robbins–Monro algorithm https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34dd/d8865569c2c32dec9bf7ffc817ff42faaa01.pdf. And there is a formula that I really don't understand at (3) of an article. It says that  Pr[Y(x) <= y] = H(y | x), such that $M(x) = \int _{ -\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ yd(H|y) } $.

I also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function. And i know $Pr(a \le X \le b) = \int _{ a }^{ b }{ f(x)d(x) }$, 
it seems a bit related.

So I have a few questions:

1/ what is H(x|y)?

2/ Why $M(x) = \int _{ -\infty  }^{ \infty  }{ yd(H|y) } $ ?

Comment: That’s not the expression for $M(x)$ that is mentioned in the paper.

Comment: @WimC Given that the person asking is not an expert, this could clearly be a typo on his part. You could still try to answer though